# show field only if 2 conditions are true?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple question but could someone help me with javascript which will show a div based on **two** dropdown selections being true?

This is the code I have but I just want to know if this is correct?

**EDIT** SOLVED with both answers below. Thanks a lot guys!

```js
<script>
function myFunction(){
$('#LoadingPlace,#DeliveryPlaces').change(function () {
    if ($('#DeliveryPlaces').val() == '1' || 
            ["Seaport 1", "Seaport 2", "Seaport 3"].indexOf($('#LoadingPlace').val()) > -1) {
        $("{#ContainerSize1").show();
        $("#ContainerFeature1").show();
  $("#Genset1").show();            
  } 
  
 else {
        $("{#ContainerSize1").hide();
        $("#ContainerFeature1").hide();
  $("#Genset1").hide();  
    }    

 })};
</script>
```

Comment: are you try with `&&`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this : [jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/3y8n9msc/2/](https://jsfiddle.net/bharatsing/3y8n9msc/2/)

Also in you code I have found that

```
$("{#ContainerSize1").show();
```

This should be

```
$("#ContainerSize1").show();

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#LoadingPlace,#DeliveryPlaces').change(function () { 
      if ($('#DeliveryPlaces').val() == '1' && 
              ["Seaport 1", "Seaport 2", "Seaport 3"].indexOf($('#LoadingPlace').val()) > -1) {
          $("#ContainerSize1").show();
          $("#ContainerFeature1").show();
      $("#Genset1").show();            
      } 

    else {
          $("#ContainerSize1").hide();
          $("#ContainerFeature1").hide();
      $("#Genset1").hide();  
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: How your ans differ from @prasad?

Comment: I have corrected error in your code $("{#ContainerSize1").show();

Comment: need to remove { from $("{#ContainerSize1").show();

Answer (score 0):

use `&&`(its allow only both are true) instead of `||` (its allow any one true)

```
<script>
function myFunction(){
$('#LoadingPlace,#DeliveryPlaces').change(function () {
    if (($('#DeliveryPlaces').val() == '1') && (["Seaport 1", "Seaport 2", "Seaport 3"].indexOf($('#LoadingPlace').val()) > -1)) {
        $("{#ContainerSize1").show();
        $("#ContainerFeature1").show();
        $("#Genset1").show();            
        } 

    else {
        $("{#ContainerSize1").hide();
        $("#ContainerFeature1").hide();
        $("#Genset1").hide();  
    }    

    })};
</script>
```